# Performing Function per Calendar Date

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a nutrition planner which will allow users to plan meals per calendar day. As a demo, I've loaded in data from a JSON file including the meal name and calories, allowed users to pick which meal they'd like, etc. I want them to be able to do this for each day and organise it in a calendar.

Here is my code for the meal planner, which works how I'd like it to:

```
breakfastInput = input("What would you like for breakfast? ")
breakfastChoice = [breakfastChoice for breakfastChoice in breakfast if breakfastInput in breakfastChoice][0]
breakfastName = breakfastChoice[0]
breakfastCalories = breakfastChoice[1]
calories = calories - breakfastCalories
print("You have {} calories remaining.".format(calories))

lunchInput = input("What would you like for lunch? ")
lunchChoice = [lunchChoice for lunchChoice in lunch if lunchInput in lunchChoice][0]
lunchName = lunchChoice[0]
lunchCalories = lunchChoice[1]
calories = calories - lunchCalories
print("You have {} calories remaining.".format(calories))

dinnerInput = input("What would you like for dinner? ")
dinnerChoice = [dinnerChoice for dinnerChoice in dinner if dinnerInput in dinnerChoice][0]
dinnerName = dinnerChoice[0]
dinnerCalories = dinnerChoice[1]
calories = calories - dinnerCalories
print("You have {} calories remaining.".format(calories))

if input("Would you like any snacks? ") == "yes":
    print(snacks)
    snacksInput = input("What snack would you like? ")
    snacksChoice = [snacksChoice for snacksChoice in snacks if snacksInput in snacksChoice][0]
    snacksName = snacksChoice[0]
    snacksCalories = snacksChoice[1]
    calories = calories - snacksCalories
    print("You have {} calories remaining.".format(calories))
else:
    print("Your day has been planned with a remaining {} calories.".format(calories))
```

How could I allow the user to choose a date and then for this function be performed?

This way, for example, a `lunchName` and `dinnerName` can be assigned to each day.

Comment: The code provided does not provide a function. In python functions are defined with the following syntax "def function_name([input_variables]):".

Comment: @AlexanderRD I think that's a bit pedantic - I interpreted the question as using the word "function" in a typical english sense, rather than a technical sense.

Comment: @AlexanderRD I apologise for the confusion but I didn't mean 'function' technically. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @masbmf03 thank you for the clarification how are you accessing the code you have specified from your main program

Comment: @AlexanderRD I'm not sure yet. I might turn it into a function with the line 'def main():'. I need to experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [python's `datetime` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html). As a quick example:

```
from datetime.datetime import strptime
lunchDateInput = input("What date are you having lunch on?")
lunchDate = strptime(lunchDateInput, "MM/DD/YYYY")
```

You have some big ambitions with this project's functionality, but if you play around with the datetime library and read through the documentation, you'll be able to figure out the scheduling bits as well.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll have a play with the datetime library and see what I can do. I'll get back to you.